# Find all URLS in a string and encode query string?

Tags: php, url, curl, replace, encode

I would like to find all URLs in a string (curl results) and then encode any query strings in those results, example

urls found:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue&favoritefood=sharwarma
```

to replace all those URLS found with encoded string (i can only do one of them)

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.php%3Ffavoritecolor%3Dblue%26favoritefood%3Dsharwarma
```

but do this in a html curl response, find all URLS from html page. 
Thank you in advanced, i have searched for hours.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback()` to call `urlencode` on every URL that you find in the string.

Comment: How come we are not seeing your code in your question?

Comment: Will you be having more than 1 url in a string..

P.S.-Can you clarify a bit more what you want to do

Comment: thank you, everyone, the php code (DOM) worked well.

how can i now lets say find the URLS all of them again (including image src, css url, etc) and then change/replace something there like http://www.example.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue&favoritefood=sharwarma to http://www.url.com/getpage.php?get=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.php%3Ffavoritecolor%3Dblue%26favoritefood%3Dsharwarma

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want if your CURL result is an HTML page and you only want `a` links (and not images or other clickable elements).

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();

// $html should be your CURL result
$xml->loadHTML($html);

// or you can do that directly by providing the requested page's URL to loadHTMLFile
// $xml->loadHTMLFile("http://...");

// this array will contain all links
$links = array();

// loop through all "a" elements
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName("a") as $link) {
    // URL-encodes the link's URL and adds it to the previous array
    $links[] = urlencode($link->getAttribute("href"));
}

// now do whatever you want with that array
```

The `$links` array will contain all the links found in the page in URL-encoded format.

Edit: if you instead want to replace all links in the page while keeping everything else, it's better to use `DOMDocument` than regular expressions (related : [why you shouldn't use regex to handle HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)), here's an edited version of my code that replaces every link with its URL-encoded equivalent and then saves the page into a variable :

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();

// $html should be your CURL result
$xml->loadHTML($html);

// loop through all "a" elements
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName("a") as $link) {
    // gets original (non URL-encoded link)
    $original = $link->getAttribute("href");

    // sets new link to URL-encoded format
    $link->setAttribute("href", urlencode($original));
}

// save modified page to a variable
$page = $xml->saveHTML();

// now do whatever you want with that modified page, for example you can "echo" it
echo $page;
```

*Code based on [this](http://www.jaygilford.com/php/php-dom-get-all-pagelinks/)*.

Comment: don't use htmlDOM for trace html. this quastion says 'how to find urls in text `not html` '

Comment: @MahmoudEskandari `find all URLs in a string (curl results)` and `find all URLS from html page` clearly say that the OP wants to work with an HTML page, and in my opinion this is the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: Hi, thank you both if you however when I add the exact php below, providing $xxx is my html result, i get a blank screen...

Comment: thank you, that seems to work...  just had to do yum install php-xml

Comment: how can i now lets say find the URLS all of them again (including image src, css url,  etc) and then change/replace something there like http://www.example.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue&favoritefood=sharwarma to http://www.url.com/getpage.php?get=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.php%3Ffavoritecolor%3Dblue%26favoritefood%3Dsharwarma

Answer (score 0):

Do not use php Dom directly, it will slow down your execution time, use simplehtmldom, its easy

```
function decodes($data){
foreach($data->find('a') as $hres){
$bbs=$hres->href;
$hres->__set("href", urlencode($bbs));
}
return $data;
}
```